# What technology I have to use to make a web chat system?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, chat

I want to make an web chat system with PHP and AJAX with jQuery library, but if I do an XMLHttpRequest with a delay of 0~50ms to update the messages, I don't know if it'll work. I searched over the web trying to find a system to do this, and I found the websocket system that works great with PHP and can solve my problem, but it doesn't work on certain web browsers like IE9-.

Other question, maybe I'd have about ~300 rooms running with 5~20 users online on each room, and I want to keep all the messages on my DB. Can MySQL do it fine? And how about the CPU and RAM usage?

Comment: You want WebSockets. And you probably do not not want PHP for this. Node.js has Socket.IO which provides a Flash/XHR-based fallback for ancient browsers which lack Websocket support.

Comment: I use websockets too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a thousand ways to do this, I'll give you the "proper" way: [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP). The protocol has been designed exactly for the purpose of chats and is extremely flexible and extensible. Set up an XMPP server, such as [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im) or [any other one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_XMPP_server_software). For a web client, there's [XMPP over BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html), a reliable protocol over HTTP to interface with an XMPP server. [Strophe](http://strophe.im) for example implements it.